# Installed font on Ionic 3 app where it is not working on device

Tags: css, angular, typescript, fonts, ionic3

I have installed the `Lato-Regular.ttf` font properly using [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_oB5WvzBL0) and it is working perfectly fine on the browser. But when I deployed it to the android device using below CLI, it doesn't show the correct font.Can you tell me what should I do here?

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

*variables.scss*

```
 $font-path: "../assets/fonts";

 @import "roboto";
 @import "noto-sans";
 @font-face {
   font-family: Lato-Regular;
   src: url($font-path+'/Lato-Regular.ttf');
 }

@font-face {
    font-family: Trench;
    src: url($font-path+'/trench300tt.ttf');
}

* {
    font-family: Lato-Regular;
}

.menu-font {
    font-family: Trench;
}
```

It shows below message on the device when I debugged:

**And Errors:**

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Lato-Regular.ttf
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Trench300.ttf

*fonts folder is like below:*

[image]

Comment: Does     src: url('/assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf'); work?

Comment: that error message seems to be looking for some other font? maybe it has to do with some other font you added?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post @suraj

Comment: It should be "/assets" and not "../assets" and  font-family: 'Trench;' (with quotes)

Comment: Nope.This is template default `$font-path: "../assets/fonts";` @Vega

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug. See comments here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2675 - try moving fonts to /assets and targeting them that way

Comment: Thanks.Actually, I have found a solution after doing varies things around 4 hours :D I'll put it as an answer later today @JGFMK

Comment: @Sampath I have the same problem, could you post your answer please?